# Calculate rental Costs in excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm currently trying to setup a Calculator for Rental Cars. 
You'll put in the car category, the rental days, whether or not you want to book the fuel-flat and how many kilometers you'll travel, whether or not you'll need winter tires, if you're traveling to a certain destination and how many people will be in the car.

My Data-Spreadsheet currently looks like this:
http://i.imgur.com/P2kz6ts.png

So, if you would for example wanted to rent a Ford Fiesta for 2 days with 2 people, winter tires and fuel-flat for 80km to destination 2.
The calculator should now pick the price for 1-3 days and multiply it by 2 for two days.
To that the cost for winter tires will be added which are 3€ per day. Then it'll add the cost for the fuel-flat for 50 - 150 km, since you'll be traveling 80km. Since you're travveling to destination 2, the rental company is willing to give a discount of 15€. Finally the calculated cost will be divided by 2, since 2 people will rent the car and split the costs evenly.
That Calculation should look like this:
((30*2+(3*2)+13,80)-15)/2)
So in the End the total Cost of 32,4€ shall be displayed in a msgbox.

Now, how do i code that if the rental days are between 1-3, excel should take the values of that specific collumn and use it to calculate the cost. Moreover, if you're renting the car more than a week then the price for 6-7 days shall be used and additional days be added according to the category.

Problem fixed, look at the Answer.

Comment: please format you question properly so the code is in actual code blocks.

Comment: Unless you're allowing fractional days, the fragment you posted only passes the If when rentalDays=2.  You need to use >= and <= .   Also there are syntax problems with that line, but out of context it's difficult to make suggestions for how it should look.  You need to post more code.

Comment: I've updated the code in my original post. Since i haven't used vba for quite a while I'll need to get my head around the formatting and syntax again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code that fixed the Problem:

```
If rentaldays > 30 Then
Application.Cells(3, 3).Value = "You're trying to rent a Car for more than 30 Days. Please use the longterm program."
price = 0
End If

If rentaldays = 30 Then
monat = (Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(car, Sheets("Data").Range("A:K"), 7, False))
End If

If rentaldays > 7 Then
zusatz = price + (((rentaldays - 7) * Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(car, Sheets("Data").Range("A:K"), 6, False)))
rentaldays = rentaldays - (rentaldays - 7)
End If

If rentaldays = 6 Or rentaldays = 7 Then
woche = (Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(car, Sheets("Data").Range("A:K"), 5, False))
End If

If rentaldays > 3 And rentaldays <= 5 Then
tage = price + (Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(car, Sheets("Data").Range("A:K"), 4, False) * rentaldays)
End If

If rentaldays >= 1 And rentaldays <= 3 Then
tage = price + (Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(car, Sheets("Data").Range("A:K"), 3, False) * rentaldays)
End If
```

Comment: Should that be >= 1 and not just >1 or maye u didn't post all the code

Comment: Oh yeah, that should be either >=1 or > 0. Both will work, I'm not quite sure where the = went...

Answer (score -1):

You need to make this easier , not "smarter"

Just add more columns!

[image]

Then you have 3 simple rules  (english code)

```
if days >= 30  then 
     price = Col K   'lookup for car
     days = days - 30
end if 

if days > 7 then 
     price = price + ((days - 7) * Col J)     'lookup for car
     days = days - (days - 7)
end if

if days > 0 then
     price = price + hlookup( days, C:I  .....)    'lookup for car
end if
```

Comment: thats provided if they go over 30 days, they need to pay again based on the 7 days rules,  but you could modify this to give them the  "over days price" for all days over 30

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but the calculator should only work if you rent a car for less tehn 30 days. Otherwise, there will be a message saying, that another programme should be considered, since it'c cheaper. And while I could add more columns that would not really help me with my task.

Comment: More columns do help, read my code , just change the first if to = 30 and add an if before it for >30 with a message box

Comment: Yes, i know that more columns will essentially help me with the problem, but yet I'm trying to figure out how to work with an if-call with numbers between x and y. It will be easier if the prices get updated to update five columns rather than calculating 10 columns. And while adding more columns might be a solution, i guess there has to be a way to work with what i have here.

Comment: Agreed , there is always a solution but if u write the code and then 1-2 days  is different from 3 the code needs a rewrite

Comment: I fixed the Problem. If you're interested look at my answer. And thanks for your solution, it helped me to get my head around VBA again.